# Is there a place to upload files for other users to download?

Tags: discussion

I know the answer is probably no, but I want to share some versions of Clockwork Mod recovery that I had a lot of trouble finding. I am willing to host them myself but want to provide links to them on android.SE so other enthusiasts may find them.

I figure I might create a question: "Where can I fine different versions of CWM recovery?" then answer it myself with the links.

A different idea would be to do it somewhere on meta with a different framing.

What do you guys think?

If you don't like those ideas what if I posted the files on xda or somewhere then linked to that?

Answer (score 2):

No, SE doesn't have file hosting.  Closest thing is a special imgur subdomain (but only for images uploaded through the editor).

Linking to something external is fine — and even better if you are the uploader or have used it yourself and can vouch for its integrity.